# Microsoft Power BI REST API PowerBINotAuthorizedException

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to access datasets in PBI, but I can't get the correct permissions

I created an application in Microsoft Entra ID
To get a token I make a request:

```http
POST /{{tenantId}}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: ...

client_id={{clientId}}
&grant_type=client_credentials
&scope=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default openid profile offline_access
&client_secret={{clientSecret}}
```

I receive a response with a token:

```json
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "ey...Cw"
}
```

After this, I make a request to get dataset:

```http
GET /v1.0/myorg/groups/{{workspaceId}}/datasets/{{datasetId}} HTTP/1.1
Host: api.powerbi.com
Authorization: Bearer ey...Cw
```

And I receive a 401 response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException",
        "pbi.error": {
            "code": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException",
            "parameters": {},
            "details": [],
            "exceptionCulprit": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Following permissions are specified for the app in Microsoft Entra ID:
[Microsoft Entra ID App API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLi3w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need, and shouldn't set any app permissions in Entra ID.

You do need to grant the service principal rights in the workspace.

Comment: Thanks! I simply added my application name from Entra ID to Workspace Manage access to get it works